# Moving up hierachy with relative path

Tags: floats, lyx, directory

Is it possible to include figures with a relative path which are not in the document directory?

For example:

```
├─Folder
│ ├─Document
│ │ └─Document.lyx
│ └─Figures
│   └─Image.jpg
```

Can the figure be included with a path like `\\Figures\Image.jpg` insted of an absolute path like `C:\Users\...\Folder\Figures\Image.jpg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default of LyX when you use the browse button is that if you have a document structure like the one above, LyX will store the path as an absolute path. The reason for this is because LyX believes there's a high probability that a relative path could be broken (e.g. if you move the .lyx file). If both are in the same directory or if the .jpg is in a subdirectory, then LyX thinks there is a lower probability that the relative path would be broken so it uses a relative path.

If you want a relative path, the solution is just to edit the path directly. You can edit the text in the graphics dialog. Change it to "../Figures/Image.jpg".